# How to access a flux in the middle of a Spring Integration flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

I try to access the flux object in Spring Integration without splitting the flow declaration to two functions. I wonder how can I perform the following:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(somePublisher)
      // Access publisher here to perform something like:
      .handle(flux -> flux.buffer(Duration.ofMillis(200))
      .handle(writeToS3)
      .get();
}
```

I don't mind moving the flux operation that I'm talking about in the comments to another class (maybe for being some kind of a gateway), but it's obviously very important to me to start and the flow from the same `mainFlow` function, so it will be super clear and readable to understand what I'm doing in my application. I saw [the documentation of gateways with Monos](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#reactor-mono), but the example code is not even possible (they talk about Flux that is not inside a function and it's super hard for me as a beginner to understand what's going on there).

Answer (score 1):

The `IntegrationFlows.from(somePublisher)` start a ractive stream for the provided `Publisher`. The rest of the flow is done against every single event in the source `Publisher`. So, your `.handle(flux ->)` is going to work only if that event from the source is a `Flux`.

If your idea to apply that `buffer()` for the source `Publisher` and go on, then consider to use a `reactive()` customizer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#fluxmessagechannel-and-reactivestreamsconsumer.

So, instead of that `handle()` I would use:

```
.bridge(e -> e.reactive(flux -> flux.buffer(Duration.ofMillis(200)))
```

The next `handle(writeToS3)` is going to be performed against buffered `List` result, so be careful what you are doing and expecting in your `writeToS3`.

Comment: Thank you. It's actually doesn't work for me because the continuation of the flow (I also tested it with the mongo reactive outbound channel adapter) doesn't expect a flux of list, but a flux of messages. Do you have any idea to resolve this if I want to write to my DB in batches of time? I've been reading about [flux aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/aggregator.html#flux-aggregator) that invokes `flux.window()` and returns `Flux<Flux<Message<?>>>` and not `Flux<List<Message<?>>>`. Will it operate the same as I expected from `flux.buffer()` - write batches?

Comment: Correct. It will operate the same way. The `FluxAggregatorMessageHandler` collect message to the `window` by some `groupKey`. It can be treated as a `buffer`. You cannot perform write in batches into MongoDB because the existing `ReactiveMongoDbStoringMessageHandler` does not support a batch: plain insert or update against a single entity.

Comment: I see. So I've got to implement a specific channel adapter to support this? As for my understanding, none of the channel adapters in si supports batch then, correct?

Comment: No. That was not a goal so far. You can just implement a service method which uses a `ReactiveMongoOperations` and desired `insertAll()`. Then your previous endpoint could return a collection as a payload. It could be that `buffer()` result as well. However a `FluxMessageChannel` has to be used in between anyway. So, the framework would subscribe to the `Flux` smoothly.

Comment: I have two questions about this: 1. By saying "service method" - do you mean to implement a channel adapter that uses `ReactiveMongoOperations` and has a batch-based implementation of `insertAll()`? 2. How come the use case of batches writing have never come up? How SI can be efficient if all of its IO operations are entity-based only?

Comment: You right a POJO with a method you can call from the `handle(service, method)`. Another one is a bit misleading: SI is message-based. It does nothing with the payload. It is just an omission in that message handler impl to not deal with batch yet. Feel free to raise a GH issue. We have a batch insert support for JDBC, so I don’t see obstacles to support it for MongoDB

Comment: Ok, what you've said now about the batches that are just haven't been implemented yet for Mongo makes more sense. I'm pretty confused by your first sentence. Do you suggest I'll write a new channel adapter (and if so, what interface should it be based on?), or by saying "pojo with a method you can call from handle(svc, method)"  you mean that I can just pass this function with a class of the configurations of the writer?

Answer (score 0):

Artem's answer is great and correct, but what I was exactly looking for was:

```java
.fluxTransform(messageFlux -> messageFlux.buffer(Duration.ofMillis(200)))
```