# Reactive Spring Integration access flux in the middle of an IntegrationFlow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

I've seen the issue about [accessing flux at the middle of an `IntegrationFlow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280457/how-to-access-a-flux-in-the-middle-of-a-spring-integration-flow) and I wonder why I succeed writing logic inside the flux in the following way:

```java
public void writeToSolr(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> flowDefinition) {
    flowDefinition
        .bridge(e -> e.reactive(flux -> a ->
           flux.log("write to solr")
               .flatMap(writeToSolr)
               .subscribe()));
}
```

I wonder first of all why I never get errors thrown to the console, but when debugging I see errors.
I also want to know how can this work and why do I need the `a` variable (that always produces `NullPointerException`, even though the flow can continue and work fine). When I omit the `a` variable:

```java
public void writeToSolr(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> flowDefinition) {
    flowDefinition
        .bridge(e -> e.reactive(flux ->
           flux.log("write to solr")
               .flatMap(writeToSolr)
               .subscribe()));
}
```

I get an exception `Bad return type in lambda expression: Disposable cannot be converted to Publisher<Message<?>>` - e.g. code cant compile code due to types problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you write in that `e.reactive()` is not correct.
See documentation for that endpoint configurer option to understand its purpose:

```
/**
 * Make the consumer endpoint as reactive independently of an input channel and
 * apply the provided function into the {@link Flux#transform(Function)} operator.
 * @param reactiveCustomizer the function to transform {@link Flux} for the input channel.
 * @return the spec
 * @since 5.5
 */
public S reactive(Function<? super Flux<Message<?>>, ? extends Publisher<Message<?>>> reactiveCustomizer) {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-reactive

You cannot do those "active" operation like `flatMap()` in this configurer. You fully eliminate the purpose of the flow at all. That `flatMap` must be done in the handler downstream. Such a `bridge` does nothing meaningful. It just turns the current flow state into reactive. When the `handle()` with similar `reactive()` configurer would do the same, but also would apply a purpose of this handler - its handle part.

The `.subscribe()` is not correct to do there at all. Let the framework to deal with provided reactive stream on top of Spring Integration! That's why you mislead yourself with that `flux -> a ->`. It does compile and let you run because it is not compile or configuration part. It is indeed a callback evaluated at runtime, when you already send a message.

The `writeToSolr` may be used like this:

```
flowDefinition
    .channel(c -> c.flux())
    .handle(new ReactiveMessageHandlerAdapter((message) -> writeToSolr(message.getPayload())))
```

I think we will revise `reactive()` of the endpoint to expose only those `Flux` operators which are only for configuration. The rest is out of current endpoint configuration: it has to be done in the target handler method logic.

In addition I think we can introduce a `handleReactive(ReactiveMessageHandler)` as a terminal operator of the `IntegrationFlow` to simplify that `ReactiveMessageHandlerAdapter` usage.

Comment: Ok. Sounds awesome. Thank you! I understand from you that I should write reactive code only inside channel adapters. But I wonder how can I perform operations like `flux.buffer()` if you're saying that keeping state inside a `integrationFlow.bridge()` function is problematic (FluxAggregator doesn't work for me & I prefer `flux.buffer()` anyway). Does it really problematic to keep state inside `integrationFlow.bridge()`?

Comment: You can use that `e.reactive(flux -> flux.buffer()` on the handler I have showed you for reactive solr.

Comment: But its not always my use case. Sometimes I'd like to produce the same buffered output to multiple sinks.

Comment: e.g. when writing to multiple places, and without calculating the buffer twice. There's could even be use case of needing to perform operations on this output buffer, and that can't sit in the handler

Comment: OK. That makes sense. I think the `FluxAggregatorMessageHandler` should meet your expectations because it can produce a `buffer`. See its `combineFunction` option.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'll open an issue about that if it won't get fixed. But anyway you wouldn't recommend `flux.buffer()` in any situation? From what I understand you suggest to perform only non-stateful operations inside a `bridge`. Right?

Comment: The bridge purpose it is relay messages from one type of channel to another. Very rare situation. I forgot to mention for you that there is a `fluxTransform(Function<? super Flux<Message<I>>, ? extends Publisher<O>> fluxFunction)` operation in Java DSL for you.